# Are we allowed to use CASE inside a SUBSTRING?

Tags: sql, postgresql

(Here's a much simpler case of my actual conundrum at work)

Let's say I have a table, called 'a', with two columns named 'col' & 'foo' with the following values:

```
col|foo
A3 | f
D2 | f
```

I want to use a select statement that outputs two columns called 'letter' and 'number', where 'letter' is the first character of 'col' but with each letter shifted right in the Alphabet and 'number' is the second character of 'col' but with each number shifted down by 1; in addition to the 'foo' column. Here's the ideal output:

```
letter|number|foo
   B  |  2   | f
   E  |  1   | f
```

What query would I run to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: What happens if col is Z0?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Postgresql

Comment: @GordonLinoff Assume that Z0 isn't in the table. It doesn't need to be a generalized solution.

Comment: @TrippKinetics If there were no shifting, then I'd normally just do "substring(col from 1 for 1) AS letter, substring(col from 2 for 1) AS number" but how do I throw a CASE...WHEN inside the substring?

Comment: @GordonLinoff How A3 splited to B & 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want as:

```
select chr(ascii(left(col, 1)) - 1) as letter,
       chr(ascii(substr(col, 2, 1)) - 1) as number,
       foo
```

This uses the `ascii()` function to get the ASCII value for the characters, followed by the `chr()` function to convert it back to a character.  If you want `Number` as a number, not a character:

```
select chr(ascii(left(col, 1)) - 1) as letter,
       (ascii(substr(col, 2, 1)) - ascii('0') - 1) as number,
       foo
```

Comment: How would you do it if the actual shifting were hardcoded? Like explicitly stated that A -> B, D -> E, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 1?

Comment: Now that he's answered your question, you're trying to ask another question in the comments?

Comment: @FishermanfromDelacroix . . . That would be a different question and you should ask it in another question.  In that question, you should include sample data and your desired results, tag the question with your database, and it doesn't hurt to explain a bit why you want to do this unusual operation (okay, the third is to satisfy my own curiosity).

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this :

```
SELECT CASE
     WHEN Substring(col, 1, 1) = 'z' THEN 'a'
     WHEN Substring(col, 1, 1) = 'Z' THEN 'A'
     ELSE Char(CONVERT(NUMERIC, Ascii(Substring(col, 1, 1)))+ 1)
     END AS letter,
     CONVERT(NUMERIC, Substring(col, 2, 1)) - 1 AS number,
     foo  
FROM a
```

Comment: How would you do it if the actual shifting were hardcoded? Like explicitly stated that A -> B, D -> E, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 1?

Comment: It will help handle from the query. In query convert char to Ascii and then increase 1 number and then after that number convert to char so automatically char shifted next character.

Comment: I get that, but my actual situation isn't numerical shifts, but hardcoded changes.

Comment: In that case you need to add case statement means apply condition like case when char=’A’ then ‘F’.